# Is it possible to use Linq to group by changes in a series rather than simply by matching on a group item?

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

This is best explained by looking at the data.  Consider this list...

```
Data A      Data B
_______________________
A           1
A           2
B           1
B           2
A           3
A           4
```

Normal grouping functions on 'Data A' would yield the following...

```
A
  1
  2
  3
  4
B
  1
  2
```

...but we're not interested in grouping on 'Data A' but rather when 'Data A' changes, like so

```
A
  1
  2
B
  1
  2
A
  3
  4
```

Meaning we end up with three groups, not two.

Is this possible in LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [`GroupAdjacent` from moreLINQ:](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs)

```
var results = source.GroupAdjacent(x => x.DataA);
```

With just standard set of LINQ methods, you'd probably have to use `Aggregate`, which would not be any better (and IMO even worse, less readable) than using `foreach` loop.